# Does "Transaction"'s From pay for Gas of party of the transaction?

Tags: gas, etherscan, fees

There are some transfer for example native currency(ETH, MATIC), ERC-20, 721 tokens and stuff like that on a transaction then there are several "From" address.

I am confused which address paid for Gas fee.

I understand that the transaction's 'From' address on the 'transactions' list paid for Gas fee.(see attached image.) Am I correct?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds right. To be sure, click the value of the `Txn Hash` column. You will have a URL starting with `https://etherscan.io/tx` showing the transaction details.

Answer (score 0):

yes from pays the gas fees, because from is the one that to starts the transaction, so he pays for the gas fees, to understand all this better i recommend you read ethereum yellow paper

you should read this

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gas-ethereum.asp